# Django raises Template DoesNotExist when I use multiple settings modules

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7

I am trying to use multiple settings modules, one for production, one base and one local that won't go into the version control (git in my case). And Django raises TemplateDoesExist and the template is there. All my settings files are in the settings folder inside.

This is the base.py : http://pastebin.com/Ek4vzyCa

This is the local.py : http://pastebin.com/S9AAVhH8

This is the production.py: http://pastebin.com/Zw8bhBfk

And the manage.py: http://pastebin.com/i4AAP1Ce

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sebastian/Envs/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages      /django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/sebastian/Envs/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sebastian/Documents/project-spartan/basicpages/views.py", line 24, in home
'categories': categories
File "/home/sebastian/Envs/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/home/sebastian/Envs/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
```

File "/home/sebastian/Envs/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 43, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: basicpages/index.html
[28/Apr/2016 19:47:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 86041

Comment: It would be a very very long question.

Comment: Show the traceback please. Are you trying to start it locally?

Comment: Show your project structure also. And what about the way you are running the project? Just `python manage.py runserver` without any parameters?

Comment: Where is the `basicpages/index.html` template that you say is there, but Django cannot find?

Comment: It it in the project folder/templates

Answer (score 0):

You could use a settings only for local development, using the `settings` param in `runserver` command:

```
$ python manage.py runserver --settings=Spartan.local
```

So you can push to git only the production settings.